# How can I sort the output of awk, disregarding a certain character?

Tags: sorting, awk, text-editing, text-manipulation

I am trying to print out the Chinese font I have in my laptop, and sort the output with respect to their name that could be referred to in `LaTeX`. This could be done with the following command:

```
fc-list :lang=zh-cn | awk -F": " '{$1=""; print}' | sort
```

It finds the font list, then after first occurrence of `:` and a single space, which is where the names of the font show up. Then we of course sort it.

The problem here is though, there are fonts named like `.PingFang SC`, which is sorted to the very front and is not that consistent with the rest. Is there a way to sort disregarding the period?

It may not be a good choice to remove the period, which will change the actual name of the font and thus make the reference hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `sort -d`
(“dictionary order”, which seems to ignore non-alpha characters):

```
$ printf "Orange\n.PingFang\nRed\n" | sort
.PingFang
Orange
Red

$ printf "Orange\n.PingFang\nRed\n" | sort -d
Orange
.PingFang
Red
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much! Do you have ideas on the blank output resulted by adding the extra space?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t understand what you’re saying.  Can you edit your question to show some examples of your input (i.e., the output of ``fc-list``) and your output?

Comment: I see what the problem is, the extra space is resulted from the command `$1=""`. It is all good now, thanks!